# Hitting Firebase from django development server

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am using firebase-admin library for python. Whenever I try to hit firebase from localhost(http://127.0.0.1) i am getting below error.

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

Is there any way to test firebase from localhost.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
from irelief_api import settings
import os

firebase_credentials_file = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 
'firebase_admin.json')
cred = credentials.Certificate(firebase_credentials_file)
firebase_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com/'
})
```

Utils Function to call firebase data:

```
def postFirebaseData(url, data):
try:
    ref = db.reference(url)
    new_post_ref = ref.push()
    new_post_ref.set(data)
    return new_post_ref.key
except:
    return False
```

The above function is giving error as I am hitting firebase with HTTP.
I think firebase only respond to HTTPS server. Is there any workaround to use firebase from localhost.

Route:

```
url(r'^update-firebase$', UpdateFirebase.as_view(), name='firebase'),
```

View:

```
class UpdateFirebase(APIView):
permission_classes = IsAuthenticated,

# Get entire list of rates
def POST(self, request):

        data = {
            'id': id,
            'status': status,
            'display_text': "Hello from backend",
            }
        key = postFirebaseData(FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL, data)

    return JsonResponse({
        "error": False,
        "firebase_key": key
    }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Whenever I hit update-firebase URL from postman I am getting SSL exception as a response.

Comment: What is throwing the above error (which operation/API)?

Comment: I have edited the question. Feel free to ask if you need any other details.

Comment: Is your code part of a standalone script or a web app? I can only assume it's the latter since your mention Django in the title. In that case it is still not clear what is throwing the SSL error. Is it the SDK or some client used to test the web app.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume `FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL` is just the path to your reference. In that case, I think the error is thrown by your Django server. Your app is already talking to Firebase via HTTPS (notice the `https` URL you have specified in `initialize_app()` call). In fact Firebase database is only exposed via HTTPS, so you cannot use HTTP even if you tried.